# 404 not found when retrieving Mongo Express resources inside Docker container, using Nginx proxy

Tags: mongodb, docker, nginx, docker-compose, mongo-express

I have a Docker environment containing numerous containers for web, api, mongodb, mongo express and nginx. My goal is to use Nginx to forward traffic onto the correct services. At the moment I have things working so that if i navigate to localhost/api the api appears with a message, same works for web. But if i navigate to localhost/mongo-express the service loads but the resources that mongo-express try to retrieve are all 404 not found:
[image: 404 not found shown in console]

I'm fairly new to Docker and completely new to Nginx and learning how it works. Here is my docker-compose file:
version: '3'

```
services:
  # Web App Container
  web:
    build:
      context: web
    container_name: web
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  # API Container
  api:
    build:
      context: api
    container_name: api
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  # Nginx Container
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "403:403"
    depends_on:
      - web
      - api
      - mongodb
      - mongo-express
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  # Mongodb Container
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  # Mongo Express Container
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongodb:27017/
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes:
  mongodb_data:

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

And here is my Nginx config file:

```
# nginx.conf

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /api/ {
            rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://api:3000/;
            # Additional proxy settings for the API if needed
        }

        location /mongo-express/ {
            rewrite ^/mongo-express(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://mongo-express:8081/;
            # Additional proxy settings for Mongo Express if needed
        }

        location /mongodb/ {
            rewrite ^/mongodb(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://mongodb:27017/;
            # Additional proxy settings for MongoDB if needed
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html/;
        location = /40x.html/ {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html/;
        location = /50x.html/ {
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the files being retrieved with mongo-express to resolve no problem due to the reverse proxy. I've tried tweaking the nginx config and docker-compose file by altering the location, setting `ME_CONFIG_SITE_BASEURL: mongo-express` in the docker-compose file, but nothing has worked for me.

I'm after not just a solution but for information to really help me understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Nginx configuration, any URL that starts with `/mongo-express/` is forwarded to the mongo-express container.  That container constructs its own URLs, using absolute URL paths, and it isn't immediately aware of that path prefix, so it's generating URLs that start with just *e.g.* `/public/...`, without that prefix.

The [Docker Hub `mongo-express` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express) has a specific configuration setting for this

> `ME_CONFIG_SITE_BASEURL` (default `/`): Set the baseUrl to ease mounting at a subdirectory. Remember to include a leading and trailing slash.

So you need to make sure to include this in that container's `environment:` settings.

```yaml
services:
  mongo-express:
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_SITE_BASEURL: /mongo-express/
```

The specific setting for this winds up being application- and framework-specific; there is not a universal answer that works for all containers.  For your own application code, if it's possible to use only a relative URL `<img src="assets/test.png">` this avoids the problem entirely, but with standard packaging tools like Webpack this can wind up being a little bit out of your control.

Comment: (In the name of simplicity, also consider deleting the `networks:` and `container_name:` settings from your Compose file.  In both cases, Docker and Compose will come up with reasonable default settings.  Between your backend containers, you can still use the Compose service names as host names for one container to call another.)

Comment: Making the BASE url changes has now changed my url to access mongo express to /mongo-express/mongo-express/. If i access /mongo-express/ as is I am shown Cannot GET /. Now what's interesting is the resource urls have updated to http://localhost:8081/mongo-express/public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css for example, adding in the base url which is good, that's what was needed before. Issue now is they're still not accessible because it's actually http://localhost:8081/mongo-express/mongo-express/public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css which is where the resource actually is given this BASE url change.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this. Firstly my location urls and BASE url had trailing slashes. I had added trailing slashes due to many online guides stating that i must, even Mongo express documentation states it. Alongside this, removing rewrite ^/mongo-express(/.*)$ $1 break; from my nginx config also helped.